Get podcast episode information from spotify
I'm trying to get episode show information from Spotify episode id with this code:
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='client id', client_secret='client secret')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)  
skibidi = sp.episode('1UQ7koXTRnYJ596YGNMq7u')
print(skibidi)

And from this code is always get error with message:
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/nekozu/nekomu/spo.py", line 7, in <module>    
    skibidi = sp.episode('1UQ7koXTRnYJ596YGNMq7u')   
  File "/home/nekozu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 555, in episode    
    return self._get("episodes/" + trid, market=market)   
  File "/home/nekozu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 323, in _get   
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)  
  File "/home/nekozu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 293, in _internal_call    
    raise SpotifyException( spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 404, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/episodes/1UQ7koXTRnYJ596YGNMq7u: 
    Non existing id: 'spotify:episode:1UQ7koXTRnYJ596YGNMq7u', reason: None

I try with another function like show_episodes, show, episodes. And always get same error problem.
I want to know how to get episode information. sorry for bad grammar.

Why do you think that specific episode id should exist?

@deceze it does, if you check through Spotify's web api

skibidi toilet?

It seems you have to include the episode's market, e.g.:
skibidi = sp.episode('1UQ7koXTRnYJ596YGNMq7u', market='ES')

have a look at the documentation

skibidi toilet?
